# React-Native fetch not sending body content to $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, react-redux

I'm having an issue with a POST request using React Native's fetch. The request works perfectly fine, but the $_POST variables are not appearing at all server side. I've searched around quite a bit before posting, but no dice.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? The code for the fetch request is below.

```
const dataString = `username=${email}&password=${password}`;

export default function ajaxPost(dataString, url, callback) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(dataString)
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
       callback(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

How I'm accessing it on PHP:

```
$data = 'username=' . $_POST['username'] . '&password=' . $_POST['password'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

I've also tried hardcoding the following:

```
export default function ajaxPost(dataString, url, callback) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: 'test',
            password: 'test123'
        })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
       callback(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: can you post server side code and what are you passing in dataString?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have made modifications to the original post to add the contents of the dataString and a small snippet of how I'm trying to use it on PHP.

Comment: you have writen wrong dataString. It is like `"{ username: 'value1', password: 'value2'}"`

Comment: I've tried hardcoding the values into the ajaxPost without the use of a dataString and PHP still doesn't have access to the $_POST variables. Any other ideas why it could be breaking?

Comment: On the server side, do `var_dump($_POST);` to see what the server is actually getting. You won't be able to parse the response as JSON, but you should be able to log the response to the console and see what's there.

Comment: Hey, Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

```
export default function ajaxPost(email,password, url, callback) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
         user:{
           username: email,
           password: password,
         }
       })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
       callback(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

now access the username and password

```
$_POST['user']['username'], $_POST['user']['password']
```

Comment: I've tried this method prior, and it still doesn't recognize it on PHP. I've also tried hardcoding the values into the body. Any ideas on what other potential problems could be causing this?

Comment: problem is from php side try to print the whole $_POST array and check values weather it passing or not

Answer (score 1):

The data does not go to _POST array if sent the way you send it. You can get it on PHP side using

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)
```

Or use `FormData` object and remove json headers in js to get the data traditionally (via _POST and _GET).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same approach and it works for me. Two things you can try

1. Remove the accept key from headers. i am not using this header
2. I noticed your data object is called data string, is it possible you are stringifying the data twice?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I've tried both things, and still no dice. I have made modifications to my original post to include the contents of the dataString and how I'm accessing it on the PHP side.